# Converting a prepopulated dynamic table to an AJAX populated table

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a collection of data that I am displaying as a table. The current setup is:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@model IEnumerable<Dictionary<String,String>>

<table id="dashboard">
<thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model.FirstOrDefault())
    {
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Key)
    </th>
    }
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var i in item)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i1 => i.Value)
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>

</table>
```

The data is coming from any of several SQL tables and is being generically displayed here. The goal that I have is to take this system and have the table be created as a result of a button press following a choice on a dropdown menu. I already have the dropdown menu working. My difficulty is getting the data out of my collection so that I can display it.

I'm thinking it would be something along the lines of this:

```
<input type="button" id="OneBtn" value="1" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dashboard').hide();
    $("#OneBtn").click(function () {
        $('#dashboard').hide();
        $("#dashboard").empty();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetTableData/",
            data: { "id": 1 },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

                /*$.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var row = $('<tr></tr>'); // create new table row
                    row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.??));

                    $('#dashboard').append(row); // add to table
                });
                $('#dashboard').show();*/
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
                alert("Error");
                $('#dashboard').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here though. The data being passed through the AJAX command is a List of Dictionary objects. The alert proves that by displaying:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]
```

What is the correct way to display this information?

EDIT: 
I realized that the data I was passing was wrong. I forgot to send it as a JSON request. After that, the alert showed that it was receiving a series of objects instead.

Comment: Include your `GetTableData()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I used was this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dashboard').hide();
        $("#OneBtn").click(function () {
            $('#dashboard').hide();
            $("#dashboard").empty();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/GetTableData/",
                data: { "id": 1 },
                success: function (data) {
                    var myTable = $('#dashboard');

                    if (data.length > 0)
                    {
                        var firstRecord = data[0];

                        var headerRow = $('<thead>');
                        for (var columnTitle in firstRecord)
                        {
                            headerRow.append($('<th>', {text: columnTitle}));
                        }

                        myTable.append(headerRow);

                        var record;
                        var dataRow;
                        for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex++)
                        {
                            record = data[dataIndex];
                            dataRow = $('<tr>');

                            for (var column in firstRecord)
                            {
                                dataRow.append($('<td>', { text: record[column] }));
                            }

                            myTable.append(dataRow);
                        }
                    }
                    $('#dashboard').show();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
                    alert("Error");
                    $('#dashboard').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This creates the rows being named after the column headers and displays the table. Hopefully this can be a useful solution to others that run into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have partial view for showing table. Then you can return partial view from your `GetTableData` action in your `Home` controller

```
public Action GetTableData(int id)
{
 //get data from database and fill it in your view model
 return PartialView("_MyTableView",model);
}
```

In ajax success call you can just do this

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetTableData/",
            data: { "id": 1 },
            success: function (data) {
               $('#dashboard').empty().html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
                alert("Error");
                $('#dashboard').hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried this method, but nothing ended up being displayed. I ended up finding another way to accomplish my task. Thanks though.